# To use GitHub action cache what do I set as the value for the "key" in the workflows.yml file?

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to use Github actions to deploy to S3. I have created my .github/workflows directory and been following a tutorial to help me write my workflows.yml file.

Everything seems to be working well until I come to needing to cache node_modules. The tutorial I was following doesn't elaborate or explain what value needs to be added to the "key" and where to get this value from. Currently I have just used the name of my repo, but I don't think this is correct. This is how the cache section of my .yml file looks now...

```
- name: Caching Gatsby
        id: gatsby-cache-build
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: |
            public
            .cache
            node_modules
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gatsby-${{ github.run_id }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gatsby-
```

The error I receive when my action runs in Github is "Cache not found for input keys: Linux-gatsby-1563397146, Linux-gatsby-"

I've tried reading documentation on Github about the use of these keys but I'm finding them too hard to follow. I think there are specific values I need to use here depending on how the build script is running and how I do my installs. I'm allowing the build to run on ubuntu-latest and I use npm to do my installs and run build.

Can anyone tell me, what value do I use next to "key" and "restore-keys" and where do I get these from?

Comment: The key identifies your cached values. That is, the key should change if the cached values change. So if you use your repository name, then the key won't change if your cached values (dependencies) change and you'll restore an old version of the cache even though your dependencies have changed. I'm assuming you're using npm or yarn to install? If so, you probably want to use a hash of the file's contents as the key. With that, once the dependencies change (changed lock file contents), the key is going to change and the cache is invalidated.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @rethab. So that value I have no wplaced for "key" is `${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}` and for "restore-keys"  `${{ runner.OS }}-npm-cache-`. Does this seem correct? This seems to create a key "Linux-npm-cache-992827c37856fa61e034269a031afc3f7f538fcf04987dcd8cca1371eac95cca" but it informs me that " Cache not found for input keys: Linux-npm-cache-992827c37856fa61e034269a031afc3f7f538fcf04987dcd8cca1371eac95cca, Linux-npm-cache-"

Comment: I don't think you need the input `restore-keys`. After that, the first run should say something like "not found". However, subsequent runs should successfully restore the cache.

Comment: I'm getting the same error "Cache not found for input keys: Linux-gradle-559602605445ea3240bd4830667be2407e7e9df34f4845d7516e38f44394e469, Linux-gradle-"  did you delete the restore keys ?

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as `${{ github.run_id }}` just identifies the workflow within a repo and doesn't change when you re-run, so changes to installed packages in subsequent commits will not be detected as it reuses the cache as it was when first created.

You should select a key which uniquely identifies what the cached directory will contain and changes accordingly. In your case would be the contents of **package-lock.json** files, which you can hash.

So something like this:

```
- name: Caching Gatsby
    id: gatsby-cache-build
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: |
        public
        .cache
        node_modules
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
```

Some things to note:

1. The cache will only be saved if the job succeeds
2. Caches are immutable (took me a while to discover that)
3. Caches are scoped to branches, so it would not find a cache with the same key created for another branch, except for the default branch.
4. If it doesn't find an exact match on key, it looks at the restore keys for and uses those to *populate* your directory with the contents found, but that does not count as a cache hit, so your directory will be saved to its own cache if the job succeeds (I think this is right)
5. If you don't get a cache match, the directory you are using as a cache is   just going to be the directory as found on the runner, which in some cases (like Python's site-packages) will already contain lots of files. And depending on where that directory is, it may not be cleared between runs, meaning you get lots of packages pre-installed even without a cache hit, which speeds things up, but can also mess things up.
6. The action cache functionality is a bit buggy at times, and it can fail to find caches that blatantly do exist.

Github's [own page on caching](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflow) does a decent job explaining it. It is pretty concise and worth fine-combing so you don't go assuming it works one way when it actually works another.